# How to disable Crashlytics in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, crashlytics

I'm developing an Android app and use Crashlytics to get crash-logs. This works very well when I install the APK on other devices as I can't get a stack trace in any other way.

The issue I'm having is that I'm constantly crashing the app in the emulator in Android Studio while developing. These crashes are also reported by Crashlytics, but I would like to disable them as it makes my Crashlytics Dashboard a bit messy as I do not know which crashes are made when developing and which are actual issues on released APK:s on other devices.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Please let me know the crashlytics name? Fabric or etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should disable Crashlytics if it's debug build (you can use other filters here if needed)

```
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        CrashlyticsCore disableCrashlytics = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(true).build();
        Fabric.with(getApplication(), new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(disableCrashlytics)
                .build());
     }
```

Comment: When I use the Android Emulator, is it then in the Debug build?

Comment: When you run directly or from Android studio >>Build >>Build Apk. its Debug build and debug apk.

Comment: Just so I understand, if I press the " Run 'app' " button in Android Studio and start an emulated device, does that count as a debug build?

Comment: @FelixEder typically it would....but check your "Build Variants" window and confirm `debug` is selected (or might be something like `debug<Flavor>` if you use build flavors).

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I tried it and that was correct! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to disable Crashlytics reporting when running on an emulator or virtual box, but always enable it, **even for debug builds**, when running on real devices:

```
if (Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk") || Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("vbox")) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Disabling Crashlytics reporting");
    CrashlyticsCore disabled = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(true).build();
    Fabric.with(getApplication(), new Crashlytics.Builder().core(disabled).build());
} else {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Enabling Crashlytics reporting");
    Fabric.with(getApplication(), new Crashlytics());
}
```